# Send RadRating value to server using Jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, telerik

I have a Telerik RadRating control on my webpage.

```
<telerik:RadRating ID="RadRating1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="false" Enabled="true" Precision="Exact" OnClientRating="Rating_ClientRating">
</telerik:RadRating>
```

As it can be seen that I am calling a client side function when the user clicks on control and rate by choosing stars. Client side function is mentioned below,

```
function Rating_ClientRating(sender, args) {
        var newValue = args.get_newValue();
        var oldValue = sender.get_value();
}
```

Now I can access both new and old value successfully. Now I need to post the value through JQuery Ajax and my client side function becomes like this,

```
function Rating_ClientRating(sender, args) {
        var newValue = args.get_newValue();
        var oldValue = sender.get_value();

        var postdata = new Object();
        postdata.newValue = newValue;
        postdata.oldValue = dealid;

        $.ajax(
                {
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "Posts.aspx/RatePost",
                    data: JSON.stringify(postdata),
                    contentType: "application/json",
                    dataType: "json",
                    async: "true",
                    cache: "false",
                    success: OnSuccess,
                    failure: function (response) {
                        alert("Failure: " + response.d);
                    },
                    error: function (response) {
                        alert("Error: " + response.d);
                    }
                });
    }
```

Now as soon as I add the $.ajax to the function RadRating stops working. The tooltip is displayed correctly and stars are filled on mouse over but I click on any star then it is not selected. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

1. If you have no explicit reference to jQuery the $ variable will throw a null reference
2. the dealid variable is undefined which will throw an error

Here is an example that generated a request for me:

```
            function Rating_ClientRating(sender, args) {
            var newValue = args.get_newValue();
            var oldValue = sender.get_value();

            var postdata = new Object();
            postdata.newValue = newValue;
            postdata.oldValue = oldValue;

            $telerik.$.ajax(
                    {
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "Posts.aspx/RatePost",
                        data: JSON.stringify(postdata),
                        contentType: "application/json",
                        dataType: "json",
                        async: "true",
                        cache: "false",
                        success: OnSuccess,
                        failure: function (response) {
                            alert("Failure: " + response.d);
                        },
                        error: function (response) {
                            alert("Error: " + response.d);
                        }
                    });
            }

            function OnSuccess() {

            }
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. It is still not working. I have another Javascript function on the same page and it is also calling server side function successfully. I have placed that function inside document.ready. But when I put the same method in document.ready then my RadRating control gets disabled. If I put it outside the document.ready then everything works fine except the ajax call does not work.

Comment: Do you have any script errors? Have you examined your console? Do all the requests return successfully on this page? If we can't reproduce your problem, we can't give you a solution.